# Can't select device and filter in Logcat tab

Tags: android-studio, logcat

Sometime, when I connect device to PC in android studio dissappear ability to select  device(1) and filter(2) for logcat. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[image: logcat screen]

Comment: Please look answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found that changing the window mode (e.g change to floating mode) and then changing back fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Gaëtan Fonga Click on settings icon on any window and click on Floating Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found, that changing **the size** of logcat window when in `windowed` or the `floating` mode fixes this issue *(Android Studio 3.5)*.

In more details:

- Open setting (click cog-wheel icon) inside the logcat window
- Select the `windowed` or the `floating` mode
- Resize logcat window by stretch it or making it smaller.
- Afterwards previous view mode can be selected again (e.g. dock pinned)